# About the variance and a connected integral

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

Is given a positive measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(\mathbb{R}^+)<+\infty$. Is it generally true that: $$\int_0^\infty x^2 d \mu < + \infty \space\space ^{?}\iff^{?} \int_0^\infty \left(x \int_x^\infty d \mu\right)dx \space <+\infty $$ If it's true, where can I read a good proof of this theorem if any?

Comment: @StefanHansen I just edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Tonelli, the RHS is
$$
\int_0^\infty x\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{t\gt x}\mathrm d\mu(t)\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty x\mathbf 1_{t\gt x}\mathrm dx\right)\mathrm d\mu(t)=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^tx\mathrm dx\right)\mathrm d\mu(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^2}2\mathrm d\mu(t).
$$